# Firewall blocks ICMP even with Allow rules, even when disbled

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, firewall, ping, icmp

Sometime early October (right after update Tuesday???).  My Window 7 home machine stopped responding to anything incoming.  Effectively breaking iTunes, Sonos, TiVo Desktop, RDP etc.  But all those things aside, I can't even ping the machine.

I have no blocking rules and four rules that allow ICMPv4, one for each of profiles All, Public, Private, and Domain.  All are enabled, and either connect to Program Any or System, and allow Remote address Any or Local subnet.

I've even turned the firewall off and the machine still doesn't respond to ping, and I don't have a second firewall app running.

Firewall log clearly shows the ICMP being blocked, but not much else.

netsh wfp capture start/stop yields more information.

The filterID points to a filter named "NIS Inbound Network Block V4 Filter".  Sure enough, the rule says block, but this rule doesn't even appear as an inbound rule.  As far as I can tell this rule is part of a default/builting layer for WSH (Windows Service Hardening).

So that seems to indicate that the "allow" rules in the user-editable rules are not being applied, but I don't know how that could be true because the firewall is "on".

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this further?